# List all payment methods from customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using the Java client for Stripe on my backend.

At the moment I'd like to support credit cards and bank accounts (SEPA). A customer is able to add multiple credit cards of bank accounts if he wishes to.

If I got that right, what I want is to use the [Sources API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources), which allows me to add differend types of payment methods.

However, I am not certain how to fetch *alle* created payment methods (sources) in one call.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a list of a specific customer's sources via the `GET /v1/customers/{customer_id}/sources` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list you can use a customer_id to list all the payment methods saved for a user, assuming you attached a customer_id to the user.